# Is typescript not smart enough to determine result type when drilling into object properties?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to get better at typescript and I'm trying to understand how types cascade down as you pinpoint object properties.

Here are the relevant interfaces:

```
export interface ComboboxStringItem {
    value: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}

export interface ComboboxItem extends ComboboxStringItem {
    label: string;
}

export type ComboboxData = Array<string | ComboboxItem | ComboboxItemGroup> | ReadonlyArray<string | ComboboxItem | ComboboxItemGroup>;
```

In my code, I have defined the type of a prop like this:

```
interface Props {
  facilities: ComboboxData
}
```

The `facilities` variable ends up looking like this when populated with data:

```
facilities = [
                {
                  value: 'f1',
                  label: 'F1',
                },
                {
                  value: 'f2',
                  label: 'F2',
                }
             [
```

If I do this to try and set a default value for useState to use, it fails saying that `Property value does not exist on type 'string | ComboboxItem | ComboboxItemGroup<string | ComboboxItem> | ComboboxItemGroup<string | ComboboxItem>'`:

```
const [facility, setFacility] = useState<string>(facilities[0].value)
```

I'm confused on why that is, because if I give the type `ComboboxItem[]` to `facilities`, it works fine:

```
interface Props {
   facilities: ComboboxItem[]
}

const [facility, setFacility] = useState<string>(facilities[0].value)
```

Since `ComboboxData` has an option of its type being an `Array<ComboboxItem>`, I don't get why the first method I tried didn't work. Is it because `ComboboxData` is simply too ambiguous with all the "or" operators so typescript can't derive the type of `facilities[0]` for certain? I believe this happens because `ComboboxData` includes simple `string` type in its definition which wouldn't have the property `value`, but I guess I thought typescript would be smart enough to figure out `facilities` isn't an array of string types or `ComboboxItemGroup<string>` types.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't depend on private things (`ComboboxItemGroup` is ??) or third-party things (`useState` is ??) or excised surrounding code (`facilities` as a variable is ??). The goal is so that we can copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and immediately see what you're seeing without having problems you're not asking about.